# Picking up only specific columns based on conditions on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, select, unique

I have a data frame, say

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,5,6,3,3,3,6,8,8,8,8),
             y = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4),
             z = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"))
```

it looks like this

```
   x y z
1  1 1 a
2  2 1 b
3  5 1 c
4  6 1 d
5  3 1 e
6  3 2 f
7  3 3 g
8  6 1 h
9  8 1 i
10 8 2 j
11 8 3 k
12 8 4 l
```

I would like pick unique elements from column x, based on column y such that y should be maximum (in this case say for row number 5 to 7 are 3'3, I would like to pick the x = 3 corresponding to y = 3 (maximum value) similarly for x = 8 I d like to pick y = 4 row )

the output should look like this

```
  x y z
1 1 1 a
2 2 1 b
3 5 1 c
4 6 1 d
5 3 3 g
6 6 1 h
7 8 4 l
```

I have a solution for that, which I am posting in the solution, but if there is there any better method to achieve this, My solution only works in this specific case (picking the largest) what is the general case solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% 
 group_by(x) %>% 
 slice(max(y))

#      x     y     z
#  (dbl) (dbl) (chr)
#1     1     1     a
#2     2     1     b
#3     3     3     g
#4     5     1     c
#5     6     1     d
#6     8     4     l
```

The `base R` alternative is using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(y~x, df, max)
```

Comment: I would probably `arrange` it too, if you reverse the observations the result will differ.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result using a `dplyr` chain and `dplyr`'s `group_by` function.  Once you use a `group_by` function the rest of the functions in the chain are applied within group as opposed to the whole data.frame.  So here I `filter` to where the only rows left are the `max(y)` per the grouping value of `x`.  This can be extended to be used for the `min` of `y` or a particular value.

I think its generally good practice to `ungroup` the data at the end of a chain using `group_by` to avoid any unexpected behavior.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,5,6,3,3,3,6,8,8,8,8),
             y = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4),
             z = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"))
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(y==max(y)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

To make it more general... say instead you wanted the `mean` of `y` for a given `x` as opposed to the `max`.  You could then use the `summarise` function instead of the `filter` as shown below.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(y=mean(y)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` we can use `df[order(z), .I[which.max(y)], by = x]` to get the rownumbers of interest, eg:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[order(z), .I[which.max(y)], by = x][, V1]]

   x y z
1: 1 1 a
2: 2 1 b
3: 5 1 c
4: 6 1 d
5: 3 3 g
6: 8 4 l
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,5,6,3,3,3,6,8,8,8,8),
                 y = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4),
                 z = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"))
df <- arrange(df,desc(y))
df_out <- df[!duplicated(df$x),]
df_out
```

Printing df_out

```
  x y z
1 8 4 l
2 3 3 g
6 1 1 a
7 2 1 b
8 5 1 c
9 6 1 d
```

Comment: `arrange` and `desc` are not R base functions, you should mention the package they belong to.

Comment: @Rohak, corrected the output ; and 
Jilber, added package info

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame is ordered by `df[order(df$x, df$y),]` as it is in the example, you can use base R functions, `split`, `lapply`, and `do.call/rbind` to extract your desired rows using the "split / apply / combine" methodology.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$x), function(i) i[nrow(i),]))
  x y z
1 1 1 a
2 2 1 b
3 3 3 g
5 5 1 c
6 6 1 h
8 8 4 l
```

`split` breaks up the data.frame into a list based on x. This list is fed to `lapply` which selects the last row of each data.frame, and returns these one row data.frames as a list. This list is then `rbind`ed into a single data frame using `do.call`.